# Como setar um valor em uma Spinners?

Tags: android, spinners

Tenho um **formulariohelper** que obtém o valor da `Spinners` e grava no banco, mas não consigo carregar o valor do banco no Spinners. Como eu seto o valor?

```
public Aluno getAluno(){
    aluno.setNome(nome.getText().toString());
    Log.i(TAG,"helper: "+ aluno.getNome());
    aluno.setSobrenome(sobrenome.getText().toString());
    Log.i(TAG,"helper: "+ aluno.getSobrenome());
    aluno.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
    Log.i(TAG,"helper: "+ aluno.getEmail());

   //aqui ele pegar o valor da spinner
    aluno.setSexo(sexo.getOnItemSelectedListener().toString());
    Log.i(TAG,"helper: "+ aluno.getSexo());
    aluno.setEmpresa(empresa.getSelectedItem().toString());
    Log.i(TAG,"helper: "+ aluno.getEmpresa());
    aluno.setNit(nit.getText().toString());
    Log.i(TAG,"helper: "+ aluno.getNit());
    aluno.setDatanascimento(datanascimento.getText().toString());
    Log.i(TAG,"helper: "+ aluno.getDatanascimento());
    aluno.setAltura(altura.getText().toString());
    Log.i(TAG,"helper: "+ aluno.getAltura());
    aluno.setPeso(peso.getText().toString());
    Log.i(TAG,"helper: "+ aluno.getPeso());

    aluno.setImc(imc.getText().toString());
    Log.i(TAG,"helper: "+ aluno.getImc());
    return aluno;

}
public void setAluno(Aluno aluno){

    nome.setText(aluno.getNome());
    Log.i(TAG,"Helper setAluno: "+ aluno.getNome());
    sobrenome.setText(aluno.getSobrenome());
    Log.i(TAG,"Helper setAluno: "+ aluno.getSobrenome());

    //aqui ele seta o valor pra carregar mas nao consegue
    sexo.setTag(aluno.getSexo());
    Log.i(TAG,"Helper setAluno: "+ aluno.getSexo());
    empresa.setTag(aluno.getEmpresa());
    email.setText(aluno.getEmail());
    Log.i(TAG,"Helper setAluno: "+ aluno.getEmail());
    Log.i(TAG,"Helper setAluno: "+ aluno.getEmpresa());
    datanascimento.setText(aluno.getDatanascimento());
    Log.i(TAG,"Helper setAluno: "+ aluno.getDatanascimento());
    nit.setText(aluno.getNit());
    Log.i(TAG,"Helper setAluno: "+ aluno.getNit());
```

Comment: Você quer saber como setar o *item selecionado* no Spinner?

Comment: vc quer dizer atraves do setOnItemSelectedListener?

Comment: Não entendi. O que exatamente você quer fazer?

Comment: quero pegar um valor do banco e carregar no spinner.

Comment: Eu não estou a entender qual o seu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo se eu entendi bem. Você quer que um formulário já abra com o Spinner preenchido com o valor gravado no Banco de Dados.

Para isso após preencher o seu ArrayList que vai popular o BaseAdapter ou ArrayAdapter com a lista de todos os itens do Banco de Dados no spinner desejado coloque o código abaixo:

```
String valorBanco = "Valor do Banco que deve ser selecionado no Spinner";
int posicaoArray = 0;

for(int i=0; (i <= seuArrayList.size()-1) ; i++){

   if(seuArrayList.get(i).equals(valorBanco)){

       posicaoArray = i;
       break;
   }else{
       posicaoArray = 0;
   }
}
   seuSpinner.setSelection(posicaoArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponha que seu Spinner é nomeado MySpinner, e que contém como uma de suas escolhas: "algum valor do banco".

Para encontrar e comparar a posição de "algum valor do banco" no Spinner utilize isto:

```
//Dentro desta variável conteria o valor do banco, abaixo um exemplo
String compareValue= "algum valor do banco";

//Criando o adapter
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.select_state, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

//Setando o valor
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    MySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (!compareValue.equals(null)) {
        int spinnerPostion = adapter.getPosition(compareValue);
        MySpinner.setSelection(spinnerPostion);
        spinnerPostion = 0;
    }
```

[*Fonte*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390102/how-to-set-selected-item-of-spinner-by-value-not-by-position?answertab=active#tab-top)